# Remove HX_STACK_LINE calls from hxcpp

Tags: haxe, hxcpp

I am unable to identify a compiler flag that would turn off all of the seemingly pointless (with production code) calls that are presumably mainly for tracing.

```
--no-traces
```

does not accomplish this.

Calls like:

```
HX_STACK_LINE
HX_STACK_PUSH
```

Perhaps these should be able to be turned off and the APIs that rely on them disabled if necessary for production code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was worried about this at first as well. However, [it turns out](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/hxcpp/blob/master/include/hx/Debug.h) that as long as you don't define certain variables, all of those inserted lines are removed when the C++ code is compiled.

(For reference, the variables are `HXCPP_DEBUGGER`, `HXCPP_DEBUG`, `HXCPP_STACK_VARS`, `HXCPP_STACK_LINE`, and `HXCPP_STACK_TRACE`, and none of them are defined by default)